# How to use an absolute filename in ProGuard?

Tags: android, proguard

Like the title: "How to use an absolute filename in ProGuard?"
This should be easy but i can't find what syntax to use.

This is my config file related code:

```
-injars ../../libs
-outjars ../bin/out/proguard/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars E:/_development/android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platforms/android-18/android.jar
```

I'm using AndroidStudio and unfortunatly it doesnt generate a the proguard config file for me.

The [ProGuard documentation on filenames](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#filename) only specifies relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the first line of the documentation on file names, ProGuard accepts absolute paths and relative paths. You may need to add quotes if the file names contain special characters.

Note that the Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build processes in the Android SDK automatically specify input jars and output jars for you, so you shouldn't need to specify them in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I know the documentation sais i Can use both, but it only specifies How to use relative. My question is How to use absolute and specificly what syntax to use. This is not explained in the documentation. Can you please give an example of using a absolute path. I've been guessing the syntaxt with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
file('/Users/<user-folder>/path/to/file/filename.ext')
```